# How to debug a nuxt app running in vercel

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

I have this website that is designed to calculate people's typing speed. It's being built in Nuxt. There's a button that I use to generate a new text. When I generate a new text, I basically take that text and preprocess it, breaking it into words and lines based on how they would appear on the screen. When I access the site, everything is okay – lines are all separated and functioning. However, when I press the button to generate a new text, I receive the following error:

***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')***

However, this only happens on Vercel. Locally, this issue doesn't occur, and everything works normally. I would appreciate your help both in debugging this code on Vercel and also if you know what the problem is based on the code. I'll be providing the component with the most important parts below. Thank you in advance.

```
    const data = reactive({
        text: "",
        letterIndex: 0,
        wordIndex:0,
        lineIndex: 0,
        capslock: false,
        colors: [] as string[],
        words: [] as Word[],
        lines: [] as string[],
        absoluteLetterIndexes: [] as number[][],

        started: false,
        result: {
            wordsPerMinute: 0,
            accuracy: 0,
            time: 30,
            correctCharacters: 0,
            wrongCharacters: 0,
        } as Result,

        hiddenInputValue: "",
        isMobile: false,
    })

    async function getRandomText() {
        const text = (await $axios.get('https://random-word-api.vercel.app/api?words=200')).data;
        const cleanedText = text
            .join(" ")
            .replace(/\n/g, ' ')
            .replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '')
            .toLowerCase()
            .split(' ')
            .filter((word: string) => word.length <= 6)
            .join(' ');

        setData(cleanedText);
    }

    async function setData( text: string ){
        let newWords: Word[] = [];
        let word = "";
        let start=0;

        data.letterIndex = 0,
        data.wordIndex = 0,
        data.lineIndex = 0,
        data.absoluteLetterIndexes = [] as number[][];
        data.started = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if(text[i] !== ' '){
            length++;
            word+=text[i];
          }else{
            newWords.push({
              start,
              word,
              lastWritedIndex: start,
              index: newWords.length,
              lettersLeft: length
            });
            start = i+1;
            word = "";
          }
        }
        data.words = newWords;
        data.text = text
        data.lines = await divideTextInLines();
        data.colors = (new Array(data.text.length).fill('gray'))
    }

    async function divideTextInLines() {
        
        let lines: string[] = [];
        let currentLine = "";
        let cumulativeCharacters= 0;
        const containerWidth = document.getElementById("text-container")?.offsetWidth;


        for (let i = 0; i < data.words.length; i++) {
            const word = data.words[i].word;
            const lineWithWord = currentLine ? currentLine + " " + word : word;

            const lineWidth = await getTextWidth( lineWithWord );

            if (containerWidth && lineWidth < containerWidth) {
                currentLine = lineWithWord;
            } else {
                currentLine+= " ";
                lines.push(currentLine);
                
                let lineAbsoluteIndexes = [];
                for (let j = 0; j < currentLine.length; j++) {
                    lineAbsoluteIndexes.push(cumulativeCharacters + j);
                }
                data.absoluteLetterIndexes.push(lineAbsoluteIndexes);
                cumulativeCharacters += currentLine.length;
                currentLine = word;
            }
        }

        if (currentLine) {
            currentLine+= " ";
            lines.push(currentLine);
            let lineAbsoluteIndexes = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < currentLine.length; j++) {
                lineAbsoluteIndexes.push(cumulativeCharacters + j);
            }
            data.absoluteLetterIndexes.push(lineAbsoluteIndexes);
        }

        
        return lines;
    }

    async function getTextWidth(text: string) {
        await document.fonts.ready;
        const container = document.getElementById('text-container');
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerText = text;
        span.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
        
        if (container) {
            container.appendChild(span);
            const width = span.offsetWidth;
            container.removeChild(span);
            return width;
        }
        
        return 0; 
    }
```

Observation: I tried debbuging it by sendind the code via commits and waiting for the app to reload, and i find out that the problem is happening in the divideTextInLines function